# bootstrap navbar and screen phone optimisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically the problem is the bootstrap navbar works fine when the screen size is large but once you make the screen smaller to that of a mobile phone and you click the collapse button the background of the menu is mixed up with initial background.

Keep in mind that navbar background is transparent and then change when scrolling. the problem is in a small device and navbar on the top of the page the background of menu is mixed.

HTML:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="custom-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyWebsite</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#jumbotron">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer">Download</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>



    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

</header>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000
})
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $('#custom-nav').addClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $('#custom-nav').removeClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }   
});
```

CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
    color:#fff;
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
CSS
    }
#custom-nav {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border: 0;
box-shadow: none;
z-index: 999;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease;
-moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease;
transition: background .5s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease;
    }
#custom-nav .container {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
-webkit-transition: padding-top .5s ease, padding-bottom .5s ease;
-moz-transition: padding-top .5s ease, padding-bottom .5s ease;
transition: padding-top .5s ease, padding-top .5s ease, padding-bottom .5s ease;
    }
#custom-nav.affix {
top: 0;
min-width: 100%;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
opacity: 0.9;
-webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease;
-moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease;
transition: background .5s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease;
    }
#custom-nav a{
    color:black;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
        #wrapwrap {
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
        .navbar-fixed-top {
            z-index: 999;
        }
        #custom-nav .navbar-header{
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        float: none;
        }
    }
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What exactly did you expect to see when you click the toggle button? Like a different bg-color or something? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: when clicking the toggle button, although the navbar color is grey, the menu background is still transparent, thus it gets mixed up with the initial background.

Comment: in a normal screen size the navbar is transparent but when you change it a small screen size the navbar will become grey and the problem is that when clicking toggle button the menu background is still transparent

Comment: and yes i am expecting to see different bg-color

Comment: The navbar is transparent because of this line --> #custom-nav {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);} Remove that transparent bg property and the transparency will be fixed.

Comment: I want the navbar to be transparent in normal screen size and change in small screen size

Comment: Check the answer I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the current `background-color` property from your `#custom-nav` (leave the rest of the custom-nav properties as they are) and add this to your css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #custom-nav {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/111/

Comment: Glad I could help Luka. Cheers